# change color of text when it lay abov an specific div / image

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, colors

how i can change the color of a text element like [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Xax.png) when the text is above the picture?

Can i solve it with Javascript / jquery?

Comment: You can use css - this tutorial could help: https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
h3 {
  filter: invert(1);
  background: inherit;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```